# Parsing multiple elements with Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have this in html:

```
<meta name='DC.creator' scheme='inventor' content='Chen Yonghong' />
<meta name='DC.creator' scheme='inventor' content='Chen Yuan' />
```

If I want to get first creator I can do it like this:

```
:author =>  page.at('meta[@name="DC.creator"]')[:content]
```

The question is, how do I get second one with mechanize selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
page.search('meta[@name="DC.creator"]')[1][:content]
```

`at` is equivalent to `search(...).first` so using the same selector with search and grabbing the second element found will work as long as there are truly two tags that match. If not, you'll get an exception because you can't take the index of a nil value.

And, as a FYI, Mechanize uses [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) internally to handle its HTML parsing and manipulation. Nokogiri supports both CSS and XPath selectors so you can use whichever makes it easier for you to find the tag or element you want. I lean toward CSS for readability, but use both. See the Nokogiri tutorials for more information about searching.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<meta name='DC.creator' scheme='inventor' content='Chen Yonghong' />
<meta name='DC.creator' scheme='inventor' content='Chen Yuan' />
EOT

doc.search('meta[@name="DC.creator"]')[1][:content]
=> "Chen Yuan"
```

Comment: Thanks! I've ended up using this:  :authors => page.search('meta[@name="DC.creator"]').map { |element| element[:content] }

Comment: Yes, that will return all the authors' names.

Comment: I agree that this is best. You can try to get into things like `meta[name="DC.creator"]:eq(2)` but it can get dicey wondering if the 2 applies to just the `meta` part or the `name="DC.creator"` part as well.